# More than one file was found with OS independent path 'mockito-extensions/org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker'

Tags: android, kotlin, mockito, android-testing

More than one file was found with OS independent path `'mockito-extensions/org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker'` getting this error while adding
`androidTestImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-inline:2.15.0"`

in gradle to mock final class

Comment: any solution? Facing the same issue

Comment: no, did u got any ?

Comment: did u get it to work?

Answer (score 5):

For Android, you usually just want

```
androidTestImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-android:<latest-version>"
```

You especially don't want `mockito-inline` because it configures the wrong `MockMaker` (`mock-maker-inline`) instead of `AndroidByteBuddyMockMaker` which is the only one working on Android that is distributed by the Mockito project. If you need advanced capabilities or faster mocking, head over to the [dexmaker](https://github.com/linkedin/dexmaker) project.

Comment: did u able to mock a final class in kotlin, android ?

Comment: You need Android Pie for that, please see [Mock final and static methods on Android devices](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/mock-final-and-static-methods-on-android-devices-b383da1363ad)

Comment: If one of the downvoters could elaborate on their concerns with the answer, this would help towards improving it.

Answer (score 3):

In my case I resolved this issue by removing `dexmaker` dependency from the `build.gradle`

So, I removed the below dependency

```
androidTestImplementation "com.linkedin.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:2.12.1"
```

and kept only the below `Mockito` dependency

```
androidTestImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-android:2.25.0"
```

Not sure if that your case, but it solves mine.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Koin dependency injector, I found the solution on [this Github issue](https://github.com/InsertKoinIO/koin/issues/287#issuecomment-438249343).

Try `androidTestImplementation ("org.koin:koin-test:$koin_version") { exclude group: 'org.mockito' }`

It worked for me, I hope this may help others in the future.

Comment: This approach worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The only correct answer is PowerMockito does not support the Davik VM Android uses, it is meant for a standard JVM.  So you can't use it with instrumented tests, only unit tests. I have heard there's a library called OpenDex that allows you to use PowerMockito even with Android but it seems a bit involved to setup and I haven't personally tried it.